# Windows CE reading Azure SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, azure, windows-ce

I have a Windows CE application ( CE 6, net 3.5 ) and I'd like to access and Azure hosted SQL database.

I have the database setup and a desktop test app which is happy to connect and read tables, but my CE application will not connect.

Am I trying to do something which is not possible ?

Many thanks

Mart

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must have MSSQL client library(libraries) for WinCE.

Oh, and you should provide the user name and password in the connection string. Integrated security won't work from a CE device as far as I read at the microsoft foruns.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Azure requires to you add the IP address in order to connect through the firewall.  Your desktop PC is probably connecting OK because it's IP address has been added.

What IP address is the CE device using?